# UWP: Show ListView Items arranged in a circle

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, panel

I have a ListView with <12 items bound to it. I would like to arrange these items in a circle while still being able to use the ListView features (selectedItem etc.). Scrolling is not required though.

I found this blog post [doing a similar thing in WPF](https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/02/03/1000-displaying-the-contents-of-a-listbox-in-a-circle/), could this be rewritten to be used in UWP?

Comment: What have you tried so far, i'm pretty sure you can write that panel for UWP

Comment: I did copy the code into my project but a lot of the namespace seem to be different and I'm not sure where I would look for the correct ones or if this is even the right approach.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this article http://www.codemag.com/article/1611061 it features a list that is shaped as an airport terminal... think it would be adaptable to a circle instead of rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided should work in UWP and it's the right approach to do so. You just need to update the namespaces as such:

```
using System;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class CircularPanel : Panel
    {
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            foreach (UIElement child in Children)
                child.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

            return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
        }

        // Arrange stuff in a circle
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            if (Children.Count > 0)
            {
                // Center & radius of panel
                Point center = new Point(finalSize.Width / 2, finalSize.Height / 2);
                double radius = Math.Min(finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height) / 2.0;
                radius *= 0.8;   // To avoid hitting edges

                // # radians between children
                double angleIncrRadians = 2.0 * Math.PI / Children.Count;

                double angleInRadians = 0.0;

                foreach (UIElement child in Children)
                {
                    Point childPosition = new Point(
                        radius * Math.Cos(angleInRadians) + center.X,
                        radius * Math.Sin(angleInRadians) + center.Y);

                    child.Arrange(new Rect(childPosition, child.DesiredSize));

                    angleInRadians += angleIncrRadians;
                }
            }

            return finalSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That already looks really great, thanks! The center was a bit off for me (half the item size), so I updated the calculation of the center point:
    

    `var ch = Children.FirstOrDefault().DesiredSize.Height;
    var cw = Children.FirstOrDefault().DesiredSize.Width;
    Point center = new Point((finalSize.Width - cw) / 2, (finalSize.Height - ch) / 2);`